# handsontable.com how to record input values to mysql

Tags: handsontable

For example here http://warpech.github.com/jquery-handsontable/demo/handsontable.html

Is available some tutorial (example) how the entered data record to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library already provide an example of save.php script:
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/demo/php/save.php

So you only need to edit this for your own purposes - changing SqLite to MySQL in PDO driver.

And for client-side script you can look at: http://handsontable.com/demo/ajax.html
There you have an example how to send data into PHP server.